# VLOOKUP and search for different n in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

[Edited]
I am so sorry I did not describe this very clear:
My question is about the VLookup function:
I used the code like:

```
    B5'n$CX$"
```

with the intention to let VBA go to the B5 worksheet and also determine which
"n"(either n25 n35 and so on) it has to go to.

This was not working so I am here to seek if I can get any suggestion.

Below is the original post:

I am very newbie in VBA, just started one or two times touching it.
I have modified the code as below, and my objective is to let 
VBA find the values for "DI"&i, depending on the values of "DE"&i
in the spreadsheet B5, but in B5, the number "n" which depends on the 
values of "CX"&i, and when VBA goes to look up the values of "DE"&i,
it has to determine the value of n firstly with the help of the values
"CX"&i.
The screenshot of the worksheet B5 is as below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/do6i7zeylaz0sch/B5.jpg?dl=0

My code is as below:

firstly, if "DE"&i >3.9, I would like VBA set "DI"&i = 0,
else with vlookup function. 
Thank you very much for any help and advice.
Appreciated.

```
    Sub FindPl()
    For i = 2 To 1730
    If .Cells("DE" & i).Value > 3.9 Then .Cells("DI" & i).Value = 0
    Else: .Cells("DI" & i).Value = 
    Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup($DE$" & 
    i&",'[C:\Users\chenj5\Documents\Meeting_Jan_2019\simulation of Z1.9 for 
    Ultra Multi-Focal\Meeting 0220\Dataset used for simulation]B5'n$CX$" & 
    i&", 2, True)
    End If
    Next cell
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: So, I don't see a question or mention of any errors; which is leading this towards being read as a "give me the code" question (which won't have a very good reception on this website). If you have a specific issue, it would greatly help your question to add that information; i.e. getting a specific error message on a specific line of code, code runs but output is this when it should be that, etc.

Comment: Also, in VBA, `.Cells("DI" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup($DE$" & i&",'[C:\Users\chenj5\Documents\Meeting_Jan_2019\simulation of Z1.9 for Ultra Multi-Focal\Meeting 0220\Dataset used for simulation]B5'n$CX$" & i&", 2, True)` should be all on one line. If it's on two from being too long, then `.Cells("DI" & i).Value = ` needs to become `.Cells("DI" & i).Value = _`. The underscore tells the editor the codeline continues on the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will take a stab at some **example** code... I guessed on your source data and fixed some syntax errors... spend some time updating and appropriately dimensioning.  There is too much going on/wrong with your posted code to provide anything more clear.

```
Sub FindPl()
    dim i as long, wb as workbook, OUTPUTRANGE as range, SEARCHRANGE as range
    set wb = "C:\Users\chenj5\Documents\Meeting_Jan_2019\simulation of Z1.9 for Ultra Multi-Focal\Meeting 0220\Dataset used for simulation.xlsx" 'added xlsx extension
    with wb
        set OUTPUTRANGE = .range(.cells(5,"D"),.cells(100,"D")) 'guessed... the range with the desired output
        set SEARCHRANGE = .range(.cells(5,"B"),.cells(100,"B")) 'guessed... the range where you will find .cells(i,"DE")
    end with
    with activeworkbook.sheets(1) 'FIX THIS TO FIT YOUR NEEDS
        For i = 2 To 1730
            If .Cells(i, "DE").Value > 3.9 Then 'FIXED SYNTAX ERROR
                .Cells(i, "DI").Value = 0
            Else: 
                .Cells(i, "DI").Value = Application.Index(OUTPUTRANGE, Application.Match(.cells(i, "DE").value,SEARCHRANGE, 0)) 
            End If
        Next   
    end with
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Cyril. But I have got an "Type mismatch" error in VBA, highlighted at "Set wb="path""